# PHP Regular expression to replace SQL query conditions

Tags: php, regex

Couldnt figure out how to replace values of a conditions in a sql query with PHP ,

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE a=1 
and a = '2' 
and a= "3" 
and a LIKE '%a' 
and a LIKE "a%" 
and a < 1 
and a<1 
and a >1 
and a >1 
HAVING a <1
```

So expected output will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE a=? 
and a = ? 
and a= ? 
and a LIKE ? 
and a LIKE ? 
and a < ? 
and a<? 
and a >? 
and a >? 
HAVING a <?
```

my failed pattern is:

```
#(like|<|>|=){1}[\s]{0,1}['"\s"]{0,1}(.*?)['"\s"]{0,1}#si
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(LIKE|<|>|<>|=|IS(?: NOT)?|(?:NOT )?IN)\s*(([\"'\(]).*?\3|[^\s]+)/si", "$1 ?", $query);
```

It's strict about matching beginning and end quotes (if present) around values, and also matches a few other operators and stuff like the NULL value.

But it's not perfect, so be careful

---

Edit: Here's a more comprehensive one that also handles `IN ( ... )` clauses
But nevertheless: Messing with queries is still dangerous. Worst case is that you accidentally create your own sql injection

```
$pattern = '/(LIKE|<|>|<>|=|IS(?: NOT)?|(?:NOT )?IN)
  \s*
  (
    (["\'])     # capture opening quote
    .*?
    (?<![^\\\]\\\)\3  # closing quote
  |
    \(          # opening parenthesis
      [^\)]*
    \)          # closing parenthesis
  |
    [^\s]+      # any other contiguous string
  )/six';

preg_replace($pattern, "$1 ?", $query);
```

Comment: is it possible to add IN condition to that regexp ?

Comment: @KevinLee: Updated my answer with a more comprehensive regexp

Answer (score 1):

you can do that without pattern

something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE a=%s 
and a = %s 
and a= %s 
and a LIKE %s 
and a LIKE %s 
and a < %s 
and a<%s 
and a >%s 
and a >%s 
HAVING a <%s";

$query = sprintf($query,$arg1,$arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5,$arg6);
```

or

```
$query = sprintf($query,$arrayArgs);
```

one more idea

```
$query = preg_replace("((.+)(like|<|>|<>|=)(.+)(\s*,|\n|$))Ui","$1$2'?'$4",$query);
```

Comment: actually i am trying to do opposite of it, i got %s already filled. a sql query already exec'ed. i need to make them standart and keep in array so can measure which sql format runned mostly and how long it take and other things.

Comment: not sure that i am undestood you, my english not very well
so,  wanna you get variables from query and save them into array ?

Answer (score 0):

Think this should do, just replace every match with " ? " (without quotes :)

```
((?<=like)|(?<=<)|(?<=>)|(?<==))\s*[^\s]+(\s|$)(.(?!where))*
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use the replace function, since regex ist far to slow in php and replace would give you a huge speed boost!

Like

```
$query = '...';
$query = str_replace('1', '?', $query);
$query = str_replace('2', '?', $query);
$query = str_replace('3', '?', $query);
$query = str_replace('4', '?', $query);
...
```